# Are there some phenomena or somethings which in Hinduism which not explained by science and can only be explained by scriptures/religion/supernatural?

Tags: scripture, rishi, science

An atheist argument would be everything could be explained scientifically.  Are there some phenomena which even science cant explain and can only be explained by the scriptures/rishis/sadhus?

Comment: Changing forms, possessing bodies, on cursing and blessing and it comes true etc.

Comment: science always demands an empirical evidence to accept anything as fact, which means whatever can be perceived by senses is only in the realm of science. but you cannot provide an emrical evidence for all that  is in (eg. karma and rebirth . what is a subtle body etc)., in scriptures.So no one can convince an atheist.  The following is an example, where the effects of performance of an yajna is analysed by scientists.   https://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/ancient-fire-ritual-has-positive-impact-on-environment-scientists/article2103881.ece/amp/

Comment: Can science prove to me that 'honey tastes sweet', if I refuse to taste honey ?

Comment: but there are more people who have tasted honey and it is very easy to taste honey. We can see honey . Honey is just there.More people have experienced honey. There is more scientific proof on honey.@mar

Comment: Bhakti is something that science doesn't explain( Infact that ain't the domain of Science), Science just explains the outcomes of experiments,If Bhakti marga would be an experiment performed under suitable rules as provided by scriptures, He /She is sure to get the grace of God and Science would explain it, It's just no such experiment is conducted

Comment: Time and Space are not two separate and fall under one title kaal.